# Datatype within C#

Tags: c#, types

Is there a datatype within C# that if you put to for example 0001, and add 1, will be 0002?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use int.

```
int i=1;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("0000"));
i++;
Console.WriteLine(i.ToString("0000"));
```

Here's the result:

```
0001
0002
```

Answer (score 5):

No, but you could emulate this functionality with an integer and:

```
String.Format("{0:0000}", no);
```